# Unable to clear timeout React functional component

Tags: reactjs, events, svg

I'm triggering a mouseEnter event when I hover over an svg (an image of a country), and a mouseLeave when I leave it - however my SVGs are in a map and so are stacked next to each other. I have a div that I want to go to opacity 1 when I'm over a country, but that fades out when you're not over a country. This means that if you go to an adjacent country you have to cancel the animation, however it isn't working for me.

I've tried various different ways of cancelling the timeout, as well as attaching the timer to the window object.

This is what I have, can anyone see the problem with it?

```
 const [opac, setOpac] = useState(0);

let timer = 0;

  const mouseEnter = geography => {

    clearTimeout(timer)

    setOpac(1);
  };

  const mouseLeave = geography => {

   timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setOpac(0);
    }, 500);
  };


return (
                      <Geography
                        key={i}
                        geography={geography}
                        projection={projection}
                        onClick={handleClick}
                        onMouseEnter={mouseEnter}
                        onMouseLeave={mouseLeave}

                        style={{
                          default: {
                            fill: exposureScale(
                              dict[geography.properties["Alpha-2"]]
                            ),
                            stroke: "#607D8B",
                            strokeWidth: 0.75,
                            outline: "none"
                          },
                          hover: {
                            fill: "#607D8B",
                            stroke: "#607D8B",
                            strokeWidth: 0.75,
                            outline: "none"
                          },
                          pressed: {
                            fill: "#FF5722",
                            stroke: "#607D8B",
                            strokeWidth: 0.75,
                            outline: "none"
                          }
                        }}
                      />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for this.

Like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    // do something here
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, []);
```

React will call the function `useEffect` is returning to cancel the effect.

But for your use case you don't really need `useEffect` or a timeout.

Here is a working example:

[image: Edit nifty-jones-krghx]

Comment: Thanks, I thought about using useEffect but wasn't sure... I'll give it a try!

Comment: Is there any way you could show I'd use this with the mouseEnter and mouseLeave functions